# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to use a prepared array in a PDO query.

I have the following code :

```
$wordAr = array([0] => ':1' => 'anglais,' [1] => ':2' => 'espagnol'); #Built dynamically in reality
$createTable = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE ";
$createTable .= "CandId IN (SELECT CandId FROM etiquettes WHERE speak = :1)";
$createTable .= "AND CandId IN (SELECT CandId FROM etiquettes WHERE speak = :2)";
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare($createTable);
$stmt->execute(array($wordsAr));
$result = $stmt-fetchall();
```

This give me the following error :
`Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]`...(same as title)
Usually I would execute my query like this :

```
$stmt->execute(array(
':1' => 'anglais',
':2' => 'espagnol'));
```

but this time the array is built dynamically. (I put it in this example how it's shown with a print_r.

I guess that my issue is how is construct my array but I can't find how to built it correctly.

My purpose would be that $wordAr is interpreted as the query just above. I hope my explanation were clear enough. As I'm still a noob, sometimes I do not express my needs correctly.

Many thanks by advance for any help, I'm learning every day with it.

Comment: `$wordAr = [':1' => 'anglais', ':2' => 'espagnol'];` and `$stmt->execute($wordAr);`

Comment: Show your code for constructing the array, as your problem is at that part. You cannot construct the array based on what the print_r function displays.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cannot bind pdo params like. You need to bind each param separately.

```
$wordAr = array([0] => ':1' => 'anglais,' [1] => ':2' => 'espagnol'); #Built dynamically in reality
$createTable = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE ";
$createTable .= "CandId IN (SELECT CandId FROM etiquettes WHERE speak = :1)";
$createTable .= "AND CandId IN (SELECT CandId FROM etiquettes WHERE speak = :2)";
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare($createTable);
//loop and bind each param
foreach ($wordAr as $key => &$val) {
    $stmt->bindParam($key, $val);
}
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt-fetchall();
```

Comment: Hi, Binding several params at once using array is working, I do it regularly like this : $stmt->execute(array(
':1' => 'anglais',
':2' => 'espagnol'));
Unfortunately I have not been able to create a dynamic usable array. 
But your idea of using a loop with bindparam was good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$wordAr = array(':1' => 'anglais,' ':2' => 'espagnol');
```

And then when you execute, only do $stmt->execute($wordAr);